# boto Count number of versions for a specific object

Tags: boto

I have a s3 bucket with versions on and a key with a number of version.  I was wondering if there's an efficient way of finding the number of versions of a particular key that are in the bucket.

Here's the only way I know of

```
version_count = list(bucket.list_versions().__iter__())
```

Is this information anywhere else?

It would be really nice if I could get this information through deleting a version but haven't found anything in my searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to find all of the versions of an object is to list the versions.  However, you need to be careful when listing versions because the list of objects returned could also include DeleteMarkers which should not be counted.

I found this worked:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

c = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = c.lookup('mybucket')
versions = [v for v in bucket.list_versions('myversionedobject') if isinstance(v, Key)]
```

The variable `versions` will now contain a list of actual versions and, obviously, doing a `len()` on that list will give you the number of versions.  If there is an easier way to do it, I'm not aware of it.